# Should I delete an answer that hasn't received any upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, deleted-answers

Should I delete one of my answers that hasn't received any upvotes, even if it's a good answer?

Comment: You may well get upvotes or even accepts years after you answered.

Comment: See also: [When to delete your 0 vote answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78916/when-to-delete-your-0-vote-answers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should delete an answer if it is utterly wrong; a good answer should never be deleted, even if it has not been up-voted. The fact nobody up-voted it doesn't mean it would not be much helpful for the future readers.

Bear in mind that deleting answers could cause you to be banned from answering further questions. Deleting answers doesn't automatically ban you, but it is one of the factors that are considered for answer-banning users; one of the other factors is the score your answers have.

Comment: How does the banning work in a little more detail

Comment: There aren't much details about how answer-banning works, to avoid users circumvent it. The score of your answers, and the number of deleted answers are surely two of the factors, but others could be used. Keep in mind that bad answers make you answer-banned.

Comment: Shouldn't deleting those bad answers make you less likely to banned

Comment: Answers deleted after being heavily down-voted surely contribute, but I imagine that keeping to delete your own answers before users have time to eventually down-vote them could contribute too. I can imagine a user who deletes his answers right after somebody comments about the user not having understood the question, or having given a wrong answer. If that happens often, it could be understood as the user not giving good answers.